# Gravitation and escape speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, escape-velocity

[image]

I applied conservation of energy at the surface and at the centre of earth which brought me to equation
$$- \frac{GMm}{R} =\frac{1}{2} m v^2$$
Having asked my sir, he said that gravitational potential energy at the centre would not be zero. But in the above equation I have taken point of reference as the centre.

I have a gut feeling of it to be wrong because when I derived gravitational potential energy is equation something related to infinity was considered. Can someone make me understand why would the potential energy be non-zero? What is the point of reference over here?? Please elaborate your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the surface of earth the potential is not given by formula $-GM/r$. That is the formula for the gravitational potential outside of earth (when all of its mass acts as if it was located at the center). So you can compare with it the potential energy at $r=\infty$ with potential energy at the surface ($r=R$):
$$E_p(\infty) - E_p(R) = 0 - \left(-\frac{GMm}{R}\right) = \frac{GMm}{R}$$
From this you can calculate escape velocity.

However, if you want to calculate the gravitational field under the surface of the Earth, this formula no longer applies, and you need to calculate the gravitational field differently. You need to use the Gauss's law for Newtonian gravity (analogous to the one from electrodynamics). It says that the flux of gravitational field through a closed surface is equal to $4\pi G M'$, where $M'$ is the mass enclosed inside the surface. That means that when you're at distance $r<R$ from the center of Earth effectively only the mass inside the radius $r$ is still pulling you deeper. That mass is proportional to the volume (neglecting changes of density inside the Earth) so $M' = M r^3/R^3$ and the force of gravity you feel as you approach the center of earth is given by
$$ F(r) = -\frac{GM'm}{r^2} = -\frac{GMm}{R^3} r$$
Integrating that force you can finde the differnce between potential energy between the center and the surface:
$$ E_p(R)-E_p(0) = -\int_0^R F(r) dr = \frac{GMm}{R^3}\int_0^R rdr = \frac{GMm}{2R}$$
From this you calculate the velocity you'd gain on your journey to the center of Earth.

EDIT: I do not need to specify the point of referrence if all that I calculate is the difference of potential energies, and that's all that's necessary. But if you insist, there are many ways to set a point of reference:

If the point of reference is taken is taken at the center of the earth, the potential energy is given by
$$ E_p(r) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} \frac{GMm}{2R^3} r^2 & \text{for } r\le R \\ -\frac{GMm}{r} + \frac{3GMm}{2R}& \text{for }r\ge R\end{array} \right.  $$
The constant needs to be added in the region $r\ge R$ to make the potential energy continuous.

Another way is to take the point of reference in infinity, in which case
$$ E_p(r) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} \frac{GMm}{2R^3} r^2 - \frac{3GMm}{2R}& \text{for } r\le R \\ -\frac{GMm}{r} & \text{for }r\ge R\end{array} \right.  $$

You can also put the reference point at any distance from the center, but in every case the formula for potential energy will only differ by a constant.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Please mention about the point of reference which has to be taken. Where is it? And please do mention reason behind it being the point of reference. As I had taken centre to be point of reference, answer turned out to be wrong kindly shed light upon this.

Comment: I've added explanation to the answer, as it doesn't fit in the comment well